# Yii2 i18n Validation messages not working

Tags: php, validation, internationalization, yii2-basic-app

I have problem in i18n validations. Let me show what i have done. I have basic application.

In config/web.php

```
'i18n' => [
                'translations' => [
                    'app*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'yii'=>'yii.php',
                        'app'=>'app.php',
                        'app/validation'=>'validation.php',
                    ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

config/i18n.php

```
return [
    'color' => null,
    'interactive' => true,
    //'sourcePath' => '@yii',
    'sourcePath'=> __DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..',
    'messagePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'messages',
    //'messagePath' => '@yii/messages',
    'languages' => ['en','gu','ta','te'],
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'overwrite' => true,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'markUnused' => true,
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
        '/BaseYii.php',
    ],
    'only' => [
        '*.php',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
    'db' => 'db',
    'sourceMessageTable' => '{{%source_message}}',
    'messageTable' => '{{%message}}',
    'catalog' => 'messages',
    'ignoreCategories' => [],
];
```

I am not sure about what should be content of validation.php but i write like following.

```
return [
    'Name'=>'பெயர் வெறுமையாக இருக்க முடியாது.',
    ];
```

In Biodata.php (model file) rule

```
['name','required','message'=>Yii::t('app/validation','{attribute} cannot be blank.')],
```

But still i am getting English validation. I need `பெயர் வெறுமையாக இருக்க முடியாது.`
[image]

I want whole validation in translated language. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

In your validation.php file

```
return [
    '{attribute} cannot be blank.'=>'{attribute} வெறுமையாக இருக்க முடியாது.',
    ];
```